# Can I fly to Stockholm from Copenhagen if I'm from the UK?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, covid-19, sweden, denmark

There's currently an [entry ban](https://polisen.se/en/the-swedish-police/the-coronavirus-and-the-swedish-police/travel-to-and-from-sweden/) from non-EEA countries into Sweden. It's due to expire on the 31st October, but it has been extended before and I find it likely that it will be extended again.

If I'm from the UK and want to go to Sweden, I would need to be in one of their exemptions. However, the page also states that Nordic countries (inc. Denmark) are exempt, and they only apply these regulations according to the last country you entered from. Denmark does not appear to have any entry ban and [does not](https://en.coronasmitte.dk/rules-and-regulations/entry-into-denmark/categorization-of-countries) require a COVID test for vaccinated travellers (UK is an orange country under their system).

If this is the case, could I not just fly from the UK to Copenhagen, and then transit into Sweden either by plane to Stockholm or Øresundståg (etc) to Malmö? Is this legal, and would any checks at the borders be faced beyond the usual security/passport?

Reading the page seems to indicate it would be fine, so apologies if this is a silly question, but I want to be sure I'm not missing anything before booking. Also, if the 'entry ban' is circumvented this easily, then what purpose does it serve exactly (other than forcing people to take more stops on their journey and inevitably mingle with more people as a result)?

Comment: Is this strictly for tourism?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got it right. Everyone can travel to Sweden from an EEA country or Switzerland, but from outside the Nordics you need the EU Covid certificate (or other approved certificates).

The ban for travel from  third countries is based on recommendations from the European council. There is also a desire to keep travel within EU possible.

The European council has also recommended countries to open for vaccinated travelers. Sweden has chosen to wait until the common EU infrastructure can handle the respective third country certificate.

So the situation with the possibility to easily circumvent the ban is rendered by

- not every country has implemented the ban
- Sweden has chosen a cautious approach to open for vaccinated travelers
- the wish for open intra-EU travel

I would recommend you to not book a single ticket from UK to Sweden since then you might need to argue about the rules when checking in for your flight and you might even be denied.

**Update 2021-10-07**
Travelers vaccinated in the UK can enter Sweden from 2021-10-11 ([press release](https://www.government.se/press-releases/2021/10/vaccinated-travellers-to-sweden-from-the-uk-to-be-exempted-from-entry-ban-and-test-requirement/))

> The Government’s decision today means that people travelling to Sweden who can present a vaccination certificate issued in the United Kingdom are exempt from the entry ban and test requirement.

> The amendments enter into force on 11 October.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. So if I book one flight from UK to Copenhagen, and another from Copenhagen to Stockholm, it is unlikely to even be questioned and definitely not denied? And since I'm fully vaccinated it seems that I will only need to take a COVID test when returning to England.

Comment: @IWannaTravelPls Yes that should be possible without problems. It is very straightforward on the link you found (https://polisen.se/en/the-swedish-police/the-coronavirus-and-the-swedish-police/travel-to-and-from-sweden/#Nordics)

Comment: @IWannaTravelPls Do remember that if you do that, missing your connection is probably your problem to deal with, even if delays are involved.

Comment: @IWannaTravelPls From Monday you can travel directly to Sweden if you have a UK vaccine certificate